# Deviation between Analytic DFT and FFT in Python

Tags: python, discretization, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Within my work, I am trying to compare analytically retrieved power spectra with ones calculated from fft packages in python.

The problem I have, is that the analytic form of the peaks I derived does not match the fft result.

The minimal example I tested for that is the fourier transform of a cosine, in which I only consider positive frequencies. Analytically, I get via a geometric sum:

\begin{align} \mathcal{F}[\cos(2 \pi n dt)] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2}(e^{-i2\pi (\nu -1)ndt}+e^{i2\pi(\nu+1)ndt}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left( e^{i2\pi(\nu-1)(N-1)dt} \frac{\sin(\pi(\nu-1)T)}{\sin(\pi(\nu-1)dt)} + \dots\right).
\end{align}

As I am only interested in positive frequencies, I leave out the second term. Now when I compare this with numerical implementations, explicitly:

```
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = 10
Nsamp = int(T*8)
t = np.linspace(0,T,Nsamp)
nu = np.linspace(0,Nsamp/(2*T),int(Nsamp/2))

sig = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

ft1 = np.abs(sc.fft.fft(sig))[:Nsamp//2]
ft2 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(sig))[:Nsamp//2]
ft3 = 1/2*np.abs(np.sin(np.pi*(nu-1)*T)/np.sin(np.pi*(nu-1)*T/Nsamp))
```

I get noticeable deviations from between the two, as shown here:

[image: Comparison Plot]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your signal has one component in it. You are double-sampling the interval endpoint. That is, your first and last samples are identical. Try using numpy.linspace() with the "endpoint=False" argument. This gives me a more "correct" result in that I get one nonzero component on the positive side of the spectrum.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, using this argument makes the issue worse for me. And how would the double sampling matter if I also do it in the analytical calculation? I'd assume the two would still match then.

Comment: Use endpoint=False in both t and nu.

Comment: That way the analytical peak vanishes completely for me due to issues with the limit.

Comment: Your first and last samples map to the same point on your signal's period. In a way, the DFT computes the Fourier transform of your sample sequence repeated infinitely, as the Fourier basis exists everywhere on the real axis. If you were to try this out manually by simply copy and pasting your sequence verbatim a few times, you'd find that this signal doesn't have the periodicity you'd expect; it's due to your "double-counting" of the endpoints of the period, hence the error you're observing.

Comment: Another way you could illustrate my point is by creating a 1d zero array called X and setting X[1] = 1 and X[-1] = 1, and then IFFT'ing the array. You will notice that you don't see repeating values at the endpoints.